# Possible to write/read from same stream simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net

I guess I could try this out before asking, but just wanted to be sure it was even possible before I wasted any time.

I'm trying to eliminate the need for an in memory or physical file buffer.  I want to download a file via HTTP, or FTP (or anything for that matter) and as the stream is getting filled, I want simultaneously start uploading that stream (via HTTP, FTP, etc) to somewhere else.

Is this even possible in .NET?  The only way I can think of doing that "traditionally" is to first allow the stream to finish, and then copy that stream from memory into another stream, but I want to use the least amount of resources (time, memory, etc) as possible.

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: "The only way I can think of doing that "traditionally" is to first allow the stream to finish" - this is simply incorrect; it has *always* been possible (indeed, common) to read chunks of a stream and throw them into a second stream, in a loop.

Answer (score 7):

This is entirely possible, no problem; but you wouldn't use the *same* stream, you would use two different ones, and pipe data from the input to the output in a loop.

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make but probably didn't make clear.  I want to use the same stream, so that's not possible?  The solutions you guys are proposing here seem to be that you have to first wait for the source stream to complete, BEFORE copying to the other stream for further processing.  What I was really asking for was using the same stream at the SAME time, so there is no delay. For example, you start downloading into STREAM and at that very instant (before is has completed) start using that STREAM for something else.

Comment: @user2524616 It was clear, and you can absolutely do this. Your confusion is about reusing the object. You do *not* use a single stream object for both downloading and uploading. You will be receiving data on one *input* stream object, and then uploading it using a different *output* stream object. You transfer data from one to the other as it comes in. You absolutely do not need to wait for the input to "complete" before doing this.

Comment: @user2524616 If you did do it the long way, when you would have gone to upload it how would of you done it then? You would of copied from a `FileStream` in to your `NetworkStream` that points at your upload location. Just use the code that you would have used there but replace the `FileStream` with the `NetworkStream` that points to your download.

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine. Recent versions of .Net support [`Stream.CopyToAsync(otherStream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or its [non-async counterpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), which is pretty much a complete solution for you.

Comment: Please see my response to dvnrrs.  I was hoping to not have to wait for the first stream to finish before copying to the second stream.  Also, I need this to work with .NET 4, so I don't have CopyToAsync available to me.

Comment: @user2524616 CopyTo and CopyToAsync don't consume the input stream immediately, they read a buffer's worth from input then write it to output. Typically a buffer would be a few (4 or so) kilobytes. CopyTo is available in .Net4, so if you can stay synchronous, then use that.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me.  I keep getting 0 byte size at the end.  It seems like I have to first set the input stream to position = 0, which defeats the whole purpose of what I'm trying to do because I need to wait until after the input stream is populated then.  I want to copy to the second stream at the same time as the first stream is being written to.